# Derivatives of (vanishing) infinite integrals

Tags: integration, analysis

Probably this is a very stupid question, but if an infinite integral of some exponented expression vanishes, e.g.:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^D} d^D \mathbf{x} \, P^r(\mathbf{x}) \cdots = 0,$$
does this imply the following:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^D} d^D \mathbf{x} \, \log (P(\mathbf{x})) \, P^r(\mathbf{x}) \cdots = \int_{\mathbb{R}^D} d^D \mathbf{x} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} P^r(\mathbf{x}) \cdots = 0?$$
(The dots $\cdots$ indicate some additional contribution, independent from $r$, which guarantees that $\int P^r \cdots d^D \mathbf{x}$ indeed vanishes.)

Comment: What is the function is only nonzero inside a finite region? Are there continuity and differentiability restrictions?

Comment: Not necessarily - for example consider the integral of:
$$\frac{(\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{x})^{2k+1}}{(\mathbf{x}^2 + a^2)^r} : k < r.$$
(it vanishes since it is odd with respect to $\mathbf{x}$). Continuity and differentiability may be supposed (for simplicity).